# reseting style on <a> makes it useless

Tags: html, css

I've come across a problem, when css code is used 
 
`a {all:unset;}`
then `<a>` tag will lose it's functionality.
any tips besides not to use the piece of code?

Answer (score 0):

when using all: unset, your cursor will change to it's parent cursor which by default is usually the text cursor ( if your link is in body, a div, etc) change your cursor to pointer in your css file.
note that it still gets redirected to its link when clicked.
the altered css code:

```
a{
all: unset;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

okay, so I've figured out, that css cannot reduce tags functionality. 
`all: unset;` will only take away all style from the element. Otherwise it's all good to go.
If an `<a>` doesn't work, go check out its `href` and `rel` properties.